# How to apply a csr certi on HAproxy?

Tags: certificate, haproxy

I got some certificates from my CA , as follows

```
1. something.csr
2. something.zip --> contains 2 .cert files.
```

I am using HAProxy and want apply them. The Haproxy already uses .pem certificate, so how do i convert/combine the above mentioned certs to get one single .pem file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate `something.csr` & `something.key` to `something.pem`, this is how HAproxy understands certificate.
Add below backend to `haproxy.cfg`
`frontend https-port443
    bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/something.pem
    mode   http`

Comment: what is the exact "order" ??

Comment: On terminal: `cat something.csr something.key > something.pem`

Comment: I mean the order in which u actually Place keyes and certs , coz it won't work if u mess up the order

Comment: The order is the same which is in my previous comment, first `csr` & then `key`.

Answer (score 5):

Concat the following into a single PEM file ordered by:

1. Private Key
2. Your domain's cert
3. Intermediate certs
4. Root cert